# Extract each value from JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I need to parse JSON data and get each value from each key into a variable so I can use it outside of the loop, I am trying here to show what I am talking about:

```
var j ='[{"name1":"test1","name2":"test2","name3":"test3","name4":"test4"}]';

var json = $.parseJSON(j);

var items = [];

$(json).each(function(key,val){

$.each(val,function(k,v){

   alert(k+" : "+ v); 
   // push here ??

 });

});

var name1 = items[name1];
alert(name1);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use the json var you alredy create you can do it by just typing json[0].name1 to get the teste1 from the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xR863/

```
var j ='[{"name1":"test1","name2":"test2","name3":"test3","name4":"test4"}]';

var json = $.parseJSON(j);


var items = [];

$(json).each(function(key,val){

$.each(val,function(k,v){

  // alert(k+" : "+ v); 
   // push here ??
    items[k] = v;

 });

});


var name1 = items['name1'];
alert(name1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var j = '[{"name1":"test1","name2":"test2","name3":"test3","name4":"test4"}]';

var json = $.parseJSON(j);
//since there is only one item in the array, it won't work if there are muliple items in the array
//in this case your can just use the first object in the array as it contains the key value pair
var items = json[0];

//use the key name1 - use bracket notation of dot notation to access the member
var name1 = items['name1'];//or items.name1
alert(name1);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EyZ8F/)